# Disable IPv6 with OpenWRT

Tags: ipv6, openwrt

When I use stock Linksys firmware on my router, my networked devices properly use IPv4 only to access the Internet.

When I use OpenWRT 15.05.1, the devices try to connect to various sites using IPv6 addresses, which would be great if my ISP provided IPv6 service, which it doesn't.

I've tried a few things which haven't worked: turning off DHCPv6, disabling the DNS caching of dnsmasq, setting dnsmasq's DHCP server to provide a static DNS server address (`8.8.8.8`), and setting OpenWRT's internal DNS server setting to use that DNS server.

How do I get OpenWRT to stop telling devices that it's OK to use IPv6?

### Results of commands on one of the networked devices

The results of `ip addr` are:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1a:80:7a:4e:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.107/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp6s0
       valid_lft 42521sec preferred_lft 42521sec
    inet6 fd7f:77c6:629f::9e8/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd7f:77c6:629f::4e3/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd7f:77c6:629f:0:21a:80ff:fe7a:4e47/64 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21a:80ff:fe7a:4e47/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1d:e0:44:04:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The results of `route -6` are:

```
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
fd7f:77c6:629f::4e3/128        ::                         U    256 0     0 enp6s0
fd7f:77c6:629f::9e8/128        ::                         U    256 0     0 enp6s0
fd7f:77c6:629f::/64            ::                         U    100 1     3 enp6s0
fd7f:77c6:629f::/48            fe80::c256:27ff:fe77:37a7  UG   100 0     0 enp6s0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 2    10 enp6s0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1   729 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   3     6 lo
fd7f:77c6:629f::4e3/128        ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
fd7f:77c6:629f::9e8/128        ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
fd7f:77c6:629f:0:21a:80ff:fe7a:4e47/128 ::                         Un   0   2     3 lo
fe80::21a:80ff:fe7a:4e47/128   ::                         Un   0   2    30 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 2    67 enp6s0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1   729 lo
```

The results of both `ping6 google.com` and `ping6 2607:f8b0:4008:808::200e` are:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: When I try to connect to some domains, an IPv6 address is used to connect, which fails as my ISP doesn't support IPv6. Instead, the connected devices should limit themselves to IPv4 addresses. This used to be the behavior when my router used Linksys's firmware, but it's now broken with OpenWRT.

Comment: Because some programs tell me, when they're connecting, what the domain name they're connecting to resolves to (something like "Connecting to example.com [IPv6 address here]"). Then it tells me that that fails. When I try later, it tells me that the domain resolved to an IPv4 address, and it succeeds. It's rather difficult to share all details, as this happens in several programs, and including all details for all those programs would be absurd.

Comment: Please try to run `ip addr` on one of the client machines and include the output in the question.

Comment: @kasperd OK, I've added that.

Comment: @Olathe Great. Now it is clear what the problem you are facing is. And I think it is a bad idea for OpenWRT to behave that way by default. I don't know how to configure OpenWRT, so I cannot tell you how to fix the configuration. But at least the question now has sufficient information that somebody with OpenWRT knowledge should be able to answer it.

Comment: The addresses you see are ULA addresses. Those are private addresses and should be fine on your LAN. Your ping6 does get a proper network unreachable message, so dual stack applications (not ping6 or any other application that is IPv6-only) that try to use IPv6 should see that and immediately fall back to IPv4. Especially browsers fall back very quickly to IPv4. Which applications are you experiencing problems with?

Comment: @SanderSteffann True. Since there is no default route, any attempt to communicate with an IP address outside of the LAN would fail instantly with `ENETUNREACH` from the local kernel. It doesn't even need ICMP in order to report that error. The question thus is, how does the application respond to `ENETUNREACH`. Arguably any application which doesn't immediately fall back to IPv4 in that case is buggy. But I think such bugs are widespread enough, that it doesn't seem like a good default to use ULA addresses on the LAN if the WAN is IPv4-only.

Comment: kasperd: I agree. Those bugs need to be solved at some point though, otherwise they will keep causing problems. Especially when homenet will become more common. So I'm trying to find them and send in patches :)

Answer (score 21):

A simpler approach would be to SSH into your OpenWrt router and execute the following commands:

```
uci set 'network.lan.ipv6=off'
uci set 'network.wan.ipv6=off'
uci set 'dhcp.lan.dhcpv6=disabled'
/etc/init.d/odhcpd disable
uci commit
```

The first command disables the IPv6 LAN interface, the second the IPv6 WAN interface, the third and fourth disables the DHCPv6 Server and `uci commit` commits the changes.

## UPDATE

It seems my information has not aged well... The settings are a bit different and these are additional bits. The information should now be up to date for 2021.

The syntax got changed a bit:

```
uci set 'network.lan.ipv6=0'
uci set 'network.wan.ipv6=0'
uci set 'dhcp.lan.dhcpv6=disabled'
/etc/init.d/odhcpd disable
uci commit
```

and then disable RA and DHCPv6 so no IPv6 IPs are handed out:

```
uci -q delete dhcp.lan.dhcpv6
uci -q delete dhcp.lan.ra
uci commit dhcp
/etc/init.d/odhcpd restart
```

You can now disable the LAN delegation:

```
uci set network.lan.delegate="0"
uci commit network
/etc/init.d/network restart
```

You might as well disable odhcpd:

```
/etc/init.d/odhcpd disable
/etc/init.d/odhcpd stop
```

And finally you can delete the IPv6 ULA Prefix:

```
uci -q delete network.globals.ula_prefix
uci commit network
/etc/init.d/network restart
```

## UPDATE 2

To quote @Kurt Fitzner:

Use ifconfig to show all the network devices and note which ones have IPv6 addresses. Then navigate through the graphical OpenWRT interface to Network->Interfaces, and select the Devices tab. For each device that had an IPv6 address, select "configure" for that device and uncheck "enable IPv6".

Comment: To avoid rebooting my router to pickup changes, I run _/etc/init.d/odhcpd stop_ right after the _uci commit_ so that dhcp server stop leasing IPV6 addresses right away ;)

Comment: @PabloBurgos Thank you so much for providing me with the hint that I needed to either run that command, or reboot my router, for these config changes to actually take effect. I thought I was going crazy when my devices were still getting IPv6 addresses after this change!

Comment: This approach did not work for me.  It seems that ipv6 settings are located in separate uci interfaces (wan6 instead of wan) tied to the same underlying network interfaces. I'm using openwrt 19.07.3

Comment: @stochastic try changing the wan to wan6. I'm not aware of any recent changes that could've possibly broken this. If this method works I will gladly edit my answer. I think I executed the commands on 19.07.1

Comment: Excellent! Just did this on my now! OpenWrt 21.02.3 on jun/2022

Comment: You have disabled ipv6 for the wan and lan interfaces.  You also need to disable for the devices, otherwise you will still get ipv6 addresses assigned to their ports. br-lan and wan and perhaps the ethX devices all need to have ipv6 disabled.

Comment: @KurtFitzner any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: @SirMuffington Yes: Use ifconfig to show all the network devices and note which ones have ipv6 addresses.  Then navigate through LUCI to Network->Interfaces, and select the Devices tab.   For each device that had an ipv6 address, select "configure" for that device and uncheck "enable ipv6".

Comment: @KurtFitzner may I add your comment into my answer?

Comment: @SirMuffington Of course!  I just wish there was an easy way to do this in UCI since the  the rest of the answer is formulated that way.

Comment: Do we need to do the first commands you listed and UPDATE 2, or just UPDATE 2?

Comment: @DanRan either the update (more complex) or update 2 (more simple). The old version is still valid for old firmware if someone is still using it ;-)

Answer (score 16):

On initial installation (or settings reset) OpenWrt generates a Unique Local Address prefix and assigns ULAs to all the devices in the network, allowing them to communicate internally via IPv6 even without global IPv6 connectivity.

This generally works fine, except in two scenarios:

1. An end device attempts to route global IPv6 traffic anyway, despite this address range not being usable for that purpose. Your routing table doesn't indicate that this is what is happening, and no commonly used operating system from the last decade or so would be doing this.
2. An application misbehaves, and attempts to make global IPv6 connections when the computer does not have global IPv6 connectivity (or more specifically, a default route). From  your description, this seems to be what is going on.

To be explicit: By advertising a ULA prefix, OpenWrt is *not* telling your devices that it's OK to access the Internet via IPv6. It is only telling them that it's OK to access your home network via IPv6.

The long-term solution is to fix the misbehaving applications. If you have run into this behavior in a particular application, you should report it as a bug to its developers.

The short-term workaround is to have OpenWrt *not* advertise a ULA prefix. You can go to **Network** > **Interfaces**, blank out the **IPv6 ULA-Prefix** box, and click **Save & Apply**. This will prevent OpenWrt from advertising a ULA prefix. If you ever reset your router's settings to defaults, you may need to do this again.

Comment: Great answer/detail. Thank you so much! Anyway to have OpenWRT generate a new ULA again?

Comment: For me, the "IPv6 ULA-Prefix" box was under: Network > Interfaces > Global network options

Answer (score 0):

/etc/modules.d contains links to kernel modules that will be loaded on boot. Simply delete the links to ip6tables, ipt6-nat and nf-conntrack6 then reboot. IPv6 will be gone for good, until you do a hard reset.

This method has the added benefit of freeing a lot more RAM as the module are never loaded.